# How to remove one child from jquery object but not change html

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code:

```
$.fn.extend({
    del: function() {

    }
  })
  var ds = $(".d");
  ds.del(ds[0])
  console.log(ds.length)
```

I hope implement jquery.del to del child from jquery childs but not change  html, how to implement it?

**update**

I can implement var matchDs = ds.del(ds[0]), but I hope a way to del child from original jquery object

Answer (score 0):

I found jquery object has #splice func, so I can use following code:

```
$.fn.extend({
    del: function (e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == e) {
          this.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }
  })
  var ds = $(".d");
  ds.del(ds[0])
  console.log(ds.length)
```